# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash error in Rails In production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt

I am unable to register a user via LinkedIn on my production site. Its showing an error like this :

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 202ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
[f842309d-189a-4edc-bafb-a6a567ea8fcd]   
[f842309d-189a-4edc-bafb-a6a567ea8fcd] BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):
[f842309d-189a-4edc-bafb-a6a567ea8fcd]   
[f842309d-189a-4edc-bafb-a6a567ea8fcd] app/models/user.rb:82:in `from_omniauth'
[f842309d-189a-4edc-bafb-a6a567ea8fcd] app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:9:in `linkedin'
```

It's working fine in my local machine.

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def linkedin
      @user = User.from_omniauth(auth_hash, current_user, session)
      remember_me(@user)
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      if !(@user.img_url == auth_hash.info.picture_url)
        @user.update_attributes(:img_url => auth_hash.info.picture_url)
      end
      if not @user.persisted?
        session["devise.linkedin_data"] = auth_hash
        render body: session.to_json
      end
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, @user)
    end
end
```

User Model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth, signed_in=nil, session)
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token unless user.encrypted_password.present?
end
```

Can someone help me understand this error and how I may be able to fix it, please?

Comment: hey, why do you det Devise.friendly_token as the password for a linked login? Generate a random password to make devise happy. SecureRandom.uuid or something like this

Comment: @SimonFranzen we use devise as well for user sign-in, I even tried using secure random, and it's throwing the same error.       
user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 unless user.encrypted_password.present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried upgrading your bcrypt to `3.1.12`?

Here is the link to [GITHUB ISSUE](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4861#issuecomment-673083601)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set all devise config secrets correctly? Check your devise initializer and your ENV variables on your production server. I think the server is missing a ENV variablee to tell bcrypt what salt to use to store the password

Comment: yes, everything is set up correctly. It's working perfectly in my local machine.